# Is there a switch that can replace Voltage Controlled Switches?

Tags: switches, schematics, symbol

This is the voltage controlled switch in the LTspice.

[image: VCS Schematic]

Is there a switch which can replace it? I need a switch for a schematic. At first, I used a transmission gate switch, but the simulation of the circuit was different than it was when using a voltage controlled switch. I want to convert a circuit from LTspice to Cadence Virtuoso, but I don't know if there is a suitable part.

I use the hspice in the Cadence Virtuoso

The size of NMOS and PMOS in the transmission gate switch is 18µ/180n and 36µ/180n. If this size is not good, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Using MOS switches is fine, but you need to tweak your values, maybe edit your schematic. For example, The signal at the input is both *positive* and *negative* in value, do you think a single ended supply will do?

Comment: i don't understand about "The signal at the input is both positive and negative in value",can you take an example?

Comment: I have updated the answer to that previous question.

Comment: The size of MOS i think is suitable for the switch,i can't modify it to the better one

Comment: This question is bad asked, in my opinion. What you want to do is design a pass/transmission gate on silicon with a certain PDK. The fact that the ideal component is available in ltspice is not relevant. What is relevant is the specification of the pass gate you want to design, I would start from Ron and maybe bandwidth, then there is area constraint, what voltages you have available to turn on the gates, charge injection... It certainly is **not** possible to design the ltspice SW component on silicon, because SW is ideal, silicon tend to be **real** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the characteristics of the existing voltage controlled switch, then select a switch with the same characteristics, otherwise the simulation output will change based on the different characteristics.

Comment: i don't know its characteristic,because i can't use the ltspice,so i ask here and want to know does anyone know?

Comment: You say that v-c switch is in LT Spice - so if it exists in the program it will have the specs....

Comment: that vc switch doesn't exist in cadence virtuoso

Comment: If you're asking how to model something in Virtuoso, you should mention that in your actual question.

Comment: So you should edit your question and explain that you are converting a circuit from LTSpice to Cadence Virtuoso - this is crucial information that you have not included....

Comment: Ok,i have edit it

Comment: You need to mention the software that you are using - your edit does not improve the question yet...

Comment: If you post a larger picture that allows us to see the rest of the schematic around the switch we will likely be able to tell you the parameters, as the voltage controlled switch part usually has it's parameters manually entered.